# Convert rational number in $\frac {p}{q}$ form

Tags: rational-numbers

Convert rational number  in $\frac {p}{q}$ form $0.40\bar 7$ (here bar is over $7$).

solution:

By solving I got the answer $367/900$ by multiplying by $10$

My friends are getting answer $4037/9900$ by multiplying by $100$

Are they correct $?$

Comment: Your friends are also right but were a little less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Just divide and see:
$$\frac{367}{900}=0.407777777\ldots=\frac{4037}{9900}$$

Answer (score 0):

That's because $4037=367\times 11,$ so
$$\frac{367}{900}=\frac{367\times 11}{900\times 11} = \frac{4037}{9900}.$$
Actually I would vote for your answer as it is the most *reduced* form.

Answer (score 0):

$$900r=1000\cdot 0.40\bar7-100\cdot0.40\bar7=367$$
$$9900r=10000\cdot 0.40\bar7-100\cdot0.40\bar7=4037$$
$$99900r=100000\cdot 0.40\bar7-100\cdot0.40\bar7=40737$$
$$999900r=1000000\cdot 0.40\bar7-100\cdot0.40\bar7=407737$$
$$999\cdots900r=100000\cdots0\cdot 0.40\bar7-100\cdot0.40\bar7=407\cdots737$$

all yield correct answers, the first one being the most economical.

Answer (score 0):

Example: just write it down:
$$0.123\overline{4567}=\frac{1234567-123}{9999000}.$$

In your case
$$0.40\overline{7}=\frac{407-40}{900}$$
or as well
$$0.40\overline{77}=\frac{4077-40}{9900}$$
or even
$$0.40\overline{77777}=\frac{4077777-40}{9999900}.$$